# best practice for labeling repeating items

Tags: oracle-apex

I have 2 pages: one for input, one for approve.

These 2 pages have same fields.

p1_field_1 (label: name)

p1_field_2 (label: surname)

p1_field_3 (label: birth place)

..

p2_field_1 (label: name)

p2_field_2 (label: surname)

p2_field_3 (label: birth place)

..

I want to be able to change their labels at once in case of need, instead of doing it on each items on different pages.

I did try to create hidden items on global page with desired labels. and call them in related item's LABEL attribute as substitution strings like &P0_FIELD_1_LABEL.

then I thought perhaps I should have created application items with constant values.

but none of them made me feel right.

what would be your advice?

Comment: My first question would be whether you really need two separate pages.  One page with an action type and some conditional logic (i.e. I assume that the fields are editable for input but read-only for the approver, there is probably an Approve button in approve mode and a Save button in input mode, etc.) would seem cleaner.

Comment: I considered it indeed. but I have different type of page processes such as insert logic, send email notification after page process etc. I know I can set triggering buttons for each process but I thought it would be smart to isolate them on page level from each other. perhaps I should start from here to decide :)

Comment: Thank you and Tony very much, I gathered both pages in one form and now it seems way better.

Answer (score 3):

As Justin Cave has said, the simplest solution would be to create a single page used for both purposes, with conditional logic to show appropriate buttons, run appropriate processes etc.  But assuming you have a need for common labels across multiple pages and need a way to keep them in sync, here is a method I have used: APEX shortcuts.  There are (at least) a couple of ways you could use shortcuts:

### Static shortcuts

Create a static shortcut for each label:

- Go to Shared Components, Shortcuts and create a shortcut called `LABEL_NAME`, type `HTML text`.  Set the Shortcut text to: `Name`
- Create 2 more shortcuts: `LABEL_SURNAME` and `LABEL_BIRTH_PLACE` with appropriate text.
- In the Name page item's Label property, put `"LABEL_NAME"` (including the double quotes).  This is a shortcut reference, so at run time APEX will replace it with the shortcut definition.

### Dynamic shortcuts

If you are going to have many labels, consider a more table-based approach:

- Create a table LABELS something like:

| LABEL_CODE | LABEL_TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| NAME | Name |
| SURNAME | Surname |
| BIRTHPLACE | Birth place |

- Create a table ITEM_LABELS:

| APP_ID | ITEM_NAME | LABEL_CODE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | P1_NAME | NAME |
| 100 | P2_NAME | NAME |
| ... | ... | ... |

- Create an APEX shortcut called e.g. "LABEL" of type `Function Body returning VARCHAR2` with the shortcut defined as:

```
    declare
       l_text labels.label_text%type;
    begin
       select label_text
       into   l_text
       from   labels l
              join item_labels il on il.label_code = l.label_code
       where  il.app_id = :APP_ID
       and    il.item_name = '#CURRENT_ITEM_NAME#';
    
       return l_text;
    exception
       when no_data_found then
          return null;
    end;
```

(`'#CURRENT_ITEM_NAME#'` will return the name of the item the shortcut is used on.)

- On every page item, set the Label property to `"LABEL"` (including the double quotes).

Comment: Hi, can I reference this "LABEL" within plsql? like apex_util.get_shortcut(p_shortcut_name => 'LABEL')

Comment: @ogun no, but what you can do (a good idea anyway) is create your own function that takes in the app ID and item name and does the look-up from your table.  Then change the shortcut so that it calls that function.  You can then also use that function in your own code.